# Resolving unresolved external symbol CSourceSeeking::CSourceSeeking(...) despite linking with the right library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, directshow

Here is the error:

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected:
>   __thiscall     CSourceSeeking::CSourceSeeking(char const *,struct IUnknown *,long *,class CCritSec *)" (??
>   0CSourceSeeking@@IAE@PBDPAUIUnknown@@PAJPAVCCritSec@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public:     __thiscall CPushPin::CPushPin(long *,class
>   CSource *)"
>   (??0CPushPin@@QAE@PAJPAVCSource@@@Z)  C:\Users\x\Desktop\PushSource\PushFilter.obj    > PushSource

Here are my libs:

> gdiplus.lib strmbasd.lib msvcrtd.lib winmm.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

What lib is CSourceSeeking in?

Comment: That says "Error 2..." What was Error 1?

Comment: Error 6 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\x\Desktop\PushSource\Debug\PushSource.dll PushSource
: The 2 and 6 is just it's index on the list with other non-errors (warnings etc)

Comment: It really is strmbasd.lib.  The libs you say you use are a very strange jumble so you are probably doing something wrong in the linker settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You have to create `Strmbase.lib`/`Strmbased.lib` yourself, apparently.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/1d38b047-cd75-4381-adde-071e3f2a5c51) Make sure it's built for your target (i.e. if your program is 32-bit, make sure it's built as a 32-bit library; same for 64-bit).

Comment: ...also make sure you build *both* the library and your program as either `UNICODE` or `ANSI`.

Comment: I built the base classes and apparently it's unicode by default so vladr was right. That solved all the errors and warnings. Had to change to use unicode. Can you post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @user71512: I just edited valdr's answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of most C/C++ API Reference pages on MSDN you will find a *References* section telling you what headers to include and what libraries to link with.

Correspondingly, in the *References* section of the [CSourceSeeking reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375200.aspx) you shall find your answer:

```
Strmbase.lib (retail builds)
Strmbasd.lib (debug builds)
```

---

**EDIT**

See [@Cornstalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543307/66516) for instructions on how to build `Strmbase.lib`/`Strmbased.lib` yourself. When you build `Strmbase.lib`/`Strmbased.lib`, make sure the library build settings match your program's build settings: 32/64 bit, `UNICODE`/`ANSI`, etc. Using different settings for one or the other will cause errors.

Comment: According to that page, i am including the lib strmbasd.lib in the linker settings and i'm still getting the error message.

Comment: @user71512 please award this to @Cornstalks if you already had `strmbase.lib` in your linker settings but had to build `strmbase.lib` yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

[CSourceSeeking class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is part of the Strmbase.lib library (or Strmbasd.lib for debug builds). Generally, MSDN states header file(s) and library(ies) requirements under "Requirements" section of a corresponding documentation page.